# Tkinter RPy2 GUI Issues

Tags: python, r, user-interface, tkinter, rpy2

I have a tcltk gui coded in R which I wish to implement via python using R's "source" command. In the past, this has been a simple implementation; I would simply call the source command using RPy2 from python and the tcltk gui would load.

However, it now seems this is not the case. I realize that tkinter is not multithreaded and this is the reason *my GUI now freezes.*

To combat this, I have attempted to create another thread in python (containing the "source" command) which acts as another thread and uses the queue function. Now, the tcltk gui from the R source command runs and is not frozen (since it has the ability to update or refresh, if you will); however, the source command is called in an infinite loop resulting in multiple instances of the R Gui being started.

**Is there a way I can call the source command only once, but have the GUI maintain its ability to accept input?**

Here is the code so far which was adapted from an example I found:

```
import Tkinter                                                                                                                                                                                                       
import time                                                                                                                                                                                                          
import threading                                                                                                                                                                                                     
import random                                                                                                                                                                                                        
import Queue                                                                                                                                                                                                         
import rpy2.robjects as robjects                                                                                                                                                                                     
from time import sleep                                                                                                                                                                                               

class GuiPart:                                                                                                                                                                                                       
    def __init__(self, master, queue):                                                                                                                                                                               
        self.queue = queue                                                                                                                                                                                           

    def processIncoming(self):                                                                                                                                                                                       
        while self.queue.qsize():                                                                                                                                                                                    
            try:                                                                                                                                                                                                     
                msg = self.queue.get(0)                                                                                                                                                                              
                print msg                                                                                                                                                                                            
            except Queue.Empty:                                                                                                                                                                                      
                pass                                                                                                                                                                                                 

class ThreadedClient:                                                                                                                                                                                                
    def __init__(self, master):                                                                                                                                                                                      
        self.master = master                                                                                                                                                                                         
        self.queue = Queue.Queue()                                                                                                                                                                                   
        self.gui = GuiPart(master, self.queue)                                                                                                                                                                       
        self.running = 1                                                                                                                                                                                             
        self.thread1 = threading.Thread(target=self.workerThread1)                                                                                                                                                   
        self.thread1.start()                                                                                                                                                                                         
        self.periodicCall()                                                                                                                                                                                          

    def periodicCall(self):                                                                                                                                                                                          
        self.gui.processIncoming()                                                                                                                                                                                   
        if not self.running:                                                                                                                                                                                         
            import sys                                                                                                                                                                                               
            sys.exit(1)                                                                                                                                                                                              
        self.master.after(100, self.periodicCall)                                                                                                                                                                    

    def workerThread1(self):                                                                                                                                                                                         
            while self.running == 1 :                                                                                                                                                                                
                rsource = robjects.r.source                                                                                                                                                                              
                rsource("biolab_gui_1.R")                                                                                                                                                                                



root = Tkinter.Tk()                                                                                                                                                                                                  

client = ThreadedClient(root)                                                                                                                                                                                        
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I have determined it has something to do with coming from python 2.6 (which my app worked) to python 2.7. This is the original problem. I am still not sure how to solve this.